# Laravel is passing another variable from blade

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a script when I display all what is in collection, I use foreach. One of all collection you can delete clicking specific button, but the problem is you can click collection with ID 17 and it will delete first existing collection, even with id = 1. I do not know what to do because i think that everything looks ok. When I dump controller I see first existing collection id. I mean that moment -> ReviewAnswerController@destroy in code

Can you help me?

```
@foreach($data->reviewAnswers as $answer)
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12" style="position: inherit; display: flow-root; float: right; background: #94969f; margin-top: 15px; margin-right: 15px; padding: 5px; border-radius: 5px; width: 80%; color: white; padding-bottom: 3px;">
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <?php $avAnswer = App\Models\UserData::where('user_id', $data->sender_id)->first() ?>
      @if(empty($avAnswer->avatar))
        <img src="{{ asset('img/lock_thumb.jpg')}}" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;  border: 2px solid white;border-radius: 50%;">
      @else
        <img src="{{ asset('/storage/uploads/avatars/'. $av->avatar) }}" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;  border: 2px solid white;border-radius: 50%;">
      @endif
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <div style="float: left;">
        {{$answer->id}}
        <b>{{$answer->sender_name}} {{$answer->sender_surname}}</b> | 
        @if($answer->sender_role_specific)
        {{$answer->sender_club_role}} ({{$answer->sender_role_specific}})
        @else
        {{$answer->sender_club_role}}
        @endif
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5"></div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
      @if(Auth::user()->role == 'admin')
      <form id="reviewAnswerForm" action="{{ action('ReviewAnswerController@destroy', $answer->id) }}" method="POST">
        {{ method_field('DELETE') }} {{ csrf_field() }}
        <button class="btn" style="background-color:transparent; float: right;">
        <img src="{{ asset('img/review-icons/delete.png')}}" style="float: right;"/>
      </button>
      </form>
      @endif
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-11" style="border-top: 1px solid; padding-bottom: 5px;">
      <p>{{$answer->answer}}</p>
      <button class="btn" style="background-color:transparent; float: right;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalreportanswer">
          <img src="{{ asset('img/review-icons/report.png')}}" style="width: 15px; height: 15px; float: right; margin-top: 10px;">
          </button>
        <div class="modal fade" id="modalreportanswer" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">@lang('main.report')</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form action="{{ action('ReviewAnswerReportController@store') }}" method="POST" class="">
              {{ csrf_field() }}
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="comment">@lang('main.reason'):</label>
                <textarea id="text" class="form-control noresize" rows="5" name="reason"></textarea>
                <h6 class="pull-right" id="count_message"></h6>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="{{ $answer->id }}"  name="reviewAnswerId">
              </div>
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">@lang('main.report')!</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have 2 method, POST and DELETE in the same Form

```
<form id="reviewAnswerForm" action="{{ action('ReviewAnswerController@destroy', $answer->id) }}" method="POST">
 {{ method_field('DELETE') }} {{ csrf_field() }}
```

Try with this , I use [Laravel Collective](https://laravelcollective.com) , it is very clear.

```
Route::delete('answer/{id}', ['as' => 'reviewAnswer.destroy', 'uses' => 'ReviewAnswerController@destroy'] );

@if(Auth::user()->role == 'admin')
    {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE','route' => ['reviewAnswer.destroy', 
    $answer->id, ] ]) !!}
@endif
```

Comment: I need this using clean html